# Vuetify 3: Use Svg as a v-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I would like to use my custom svg as a v-icon but I don't find any solutions in the Vuetify v3 documentation.

In the vuetify v2, I can do this kind of things in my vuetify.js:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  icons:{
    values: {
      test: { 
        component: Test,
      },
```

And I can use this like this:

```
<v-icon size="40">$vuetify.icons.test</v-icon>
```

How I can do the same thing in Vuetify v3 ? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Below code shows an example of adding a custom icon along with the mdi set of icons to Vuetify and using both in a component via aliases.

**vuetify.js**

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi-svg'

import folder from '@/customIcons/folderIcon.vue'
const aliasesCustom = {
  ...aliases,
  folder,
}

export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons: {
      defaultSet: 'mdi',
      aliases: {
        ...aliasesCustom
      },
      sets: {
        mdi,
      },
    },
})
```

**folderIcon.vue (your custom icon)**

```html
<template>
 <svg>...</svg>
</template>
```

**any SFC**

```html
<template>
  <v-icon>$folder</v-icon>
  <v-icon>$mdiGithub</v-icon>
</template>
```

Original source: this [thread](https://discord.com/channels/340160225338195969/1047974246485336184) in the Vuetify discord channel

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response, your folderIcon.vue contains this default export sequence: `<script>
export default {
  name: "FolderIcon",
};
</script>
` I have an error of this type: `Type '{ folder: { name: string; }; complete: IconValue; cancel: IconValue; close: IconValue; delete: IconValue; clear: IconValue; success: IconValue; ... 26 more ...; minus: IconValue; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<IconAliases>'.
  Property 'folder' is incompatible with index signature.`

Comment: Completely remove the `<script>` tag from the file.  It's only meant to have `<template>` with an inner `<svg>`